# LM335 temperature sensor library for EAGLE

Tags: pcb-design, eda, lm335

I've spent ages searching for the LM335 (http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/lm135.pdf) temperature sensor library (Symbols and Footprints) in EAGLE but with no success.

Could someone kindly point me to a download link or specifically could someone from TI request to the vendor the EAGLE libraries?

Any help is truly appreciated as I've been stuck on Google and other search engines searching for anyone/any organisation  that might have uploaded the EAGLE library for the LM335

Regards,

Alex.

Comment: When you need a component and it doesn't exist, make your own.

Comment: With _very_ few exceptions, I have started designing all of my own symbols and footprints in Eagle. It doesn't take long (after you've done a few), and that way you know exactly what you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

If you do any amount of PCB design, you *will* have to make some of your own schematic symbols and PCB footprints.  If you can't find the symbols you want quickly, it is often faster and easier to make your own, rather than conduct an exhaustive search.

The LM335 can be in one of three common packages, so you should be able to find a suitable footprint in the Eagle libraries.  The schematic symbol is just a Zener diode with an extra pin - copy a Zener symbol, and edit the copy to add the extra pin.  Ensure that the pin numbers match between the schematic symbol and the footprint.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find LM335 in EAGLE's libs, then choose another part that has the same footprint:

- SO-8 IC package
- To-92 transistor
- To-3 transistor

Your schematic won't look great but the PCB should be OK. Be sure to connect correctly!

If you want to create a library by yourself check [this](http://myhome.spu.edu/bolding/EE4211/EagleTutorial4.htm) tutorial.

Comment: Making a sloppy schematic that doesn't match the PCB is pointless.

Comment: Yeah, if you have "spent ages", you are better off just making your own. Especially if the footprint already exists. Part of your work is already done. You just have to change up the symbol.

Comment: @MattYoung I sometimes do that when I'm too lazy to draw a symbol. But it turns out it's hard to connect correctly even a 3 pin component, so I go back and make a library :-)